# problem with image delay on responsive site

Tags: image, mobile, responsive, loading

Hello developers how are you? I have a problem with my images on the website. When I put up my desktop site as a mobile site, the images take a few seconds to load. How can I resolve this? Can you help me?

This is my code:

```
<picture>
<source media="(max-width:480px)" srcset="./images/mobilesmall/piano- mobile-small.jpg">
<source media="(max-width:758px)" srcset="./images/mobile/piano-mobile.jpg">
<img class="img-course" src="./images/desktop/piano.jpg" alt="">
</picture>
```